# Firebase Initialized but not able to get token (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-wear-2.0

I am using Visual Studio 2017, Xamarin 4.5.0.486, Xamarin.Android 7.3.1.2 creating a Wear 2.0 app utilizing FireBase.  My code was working fine, but now I'm receiving the following during Initialization:

> 07-18 11:59:20.453 D/FirebaseApp( 9289): com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
>   07-18 11:59:20.481 D/FirebaseApp( 9289): com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
>   07-18 11:59:20.499 I/FA      ( 9289): App measurement is starting up, version: 10298
>   07-18 11:59:20.499 I/FA      ( 9289): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>   07-18 11:59:20.515 I/FA      ( 9289): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
>   07-18 11:59:20.515 I/FA      ( 9289):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.palarum.patient.up.wear
>   07-18 11:59:20.529 I/FirebaseInitProvider( 9289): FirebaseApp initialization successful

Even though it says "Successful" I am not able to get a token using **var token = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token**.  I get null where I used to get a token.

I'm also seeing **FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful** every once in a while.

I'm running the debugger over WiFi to the actual device (LG W280).  Google Play Services is installed and available.

I've checked my package_name, I re-downloaded my google-services.json file. All to no avail...

Anyone run into this before or have any suggestions as to what else I should check?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow still no asnwer